# PHP contact form not sending emails

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I downloaded a template for my website.
The template comes with a contact form that should work.

There is my MailHandler.php file (in French) :

```
<?php
    $owner_email='david.lobstein@gmail.com';
    //SMTP server settings
    $host = '';
    $port = '465';//"587";
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    $subject='Vous avez reçu un message depuis le formulaire de contact de votre site ';
    $user_email='';
    $message_body='';
    $message_type='html';

    $max_file_size=50;//MB
    $file_types='/(doc|docx|txt|pdf|zip|rar)$/';
    $error_text='Quelque chose cest mal passe';
    $error_text_filesize='File size must be less than';
    $error_text_filetype='Failed to upload file. This file type is not allowed. Accepted files types: doc, docx, txt, pdf, zip, rar.';

    $private_recaptcha_key='6LeZwukSAAAAACmqrbLmdpvdhC68NLB1c9EA5vzU'; //localhost


    $use_recaptcha=isset( $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]) and isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    $use_smtp=($host=='' or $username=='' or $password=='');
    $max_file_size*=1048576;

    if($owner_email=='' || $owner_email=='#'){
        die('Attention, recipient e-mail is not set! Please define "owner_email" variable in the MailHanlder.php file.');
    }

    if(preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
        die('Attention, contact form will not work locally! Please upload your template to a live hosting server.');
    }

    if($use_recaptcha){
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($private_recaptcha_key,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if (!$resp->is_valid){
            die ('wrong captcha');
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['name']) and $_POST['name'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $subject.=$_POST['name'];}
    if(isset($_POST['email']) and $_POST['email'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $user_email=$_POST['email'];}
    if(isset($_POST['state']) and $_POST['state'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['phone']) and $_POST['phone'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['fax']) and $_POST['fax'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['message']) and $_POST['message'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['stripHTML']) and $_POST['stripHTML']=='true'){$message_body = strip_tags($message_body);$message_type='text';}

try{
    include "libmail.php";
    $m= new Mail("utf-8");
    $m->From($user_email);
    $m->To($owner_email);
    $m->Subject($subject);
    $m->Body($message_body,$message_type);
    //$m->log_on(true);

    if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){
        if($_FILES['attachment']['size']>$max_file_size){
            $error_text=$error_text_filesize . ' ' . $max_file_size . 'bytes';
            die($error_text);
        }else{
            if(preg_match($file_types,$_FILES['attachment']['name'])){
                $m->Attach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'],'','attachment');
            }else{
                $error_text=$error_text_filetype;
                die($error_text);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$use_smtp){
        $m->smtp_on( $host, $username, $password, $port);
    }

    if($m->Send()){
        die('success');
    }

}catch(Exception $mail){
    die($mail);
}
?>
```

When I send a mail from the contact form, it shows me that it should have been sent because of the pop-up "Success !". But I never received any mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should be able to use Gmail. It is just really slow. Use

```
//SMTP server settings
$host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';
$port = '587';
$username = 'david.lobstein@gmail.com';
$password = 'your_password';
```

Make sure your mail library is using smtp. Else use phpmailer as others suggested with the above settings.

Comment: Thank's its what I needed ! It works perfectly ! (the port is 465 not 587)

Comment: Great it worked. Good you figured out the port. I have used 587 with success earlier, but sometimes they change it.

Comment: Would you also mark it as the correct answer? Thanks

Comment: Thanks :) Very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your gmail email as sender email `$owner_email='david.lobstein@gmail.com';`

> Either your ***sender email*** or ***recipient email*** should be an email **that is configured on your website's mail server or *cPanel***.

Due to security reasons, most hosting service providers do not allow this thing.

Change it to an email address which is configured on your website's mail server, it should work then.

Comment: I dont have any mail that is configured on my website... Do you see an alternative ?

Comment: I dont have cpanel, I'm running a server on debian from online.net

Comment: Then create an email account and go further, no need to go this long discussion for this little issue.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. After I create my email on my server can I redirect every email to my gmail account ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send email, you should download [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and write this code

```
//in localhost
 require("phpmailer/AutoloadPHPMailer");    

$mail=new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
if(isset($_POST["btn"]))
{
    try
    {
        $mail->Host='__host addres__';
        $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";
        $mail->Port=465;
        $mail->Username="__User Name__";
        $mail->Password="__Password__";
        $mail->AddAddress($_POST["to"]);
        $mail->SetFrom("__From__","__Name__");
        $mail->Subject=$_POST["subject"];
        $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
        $mail->ContentType="text/htm";
        $mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);
        $mail->Send();
        echo '<font color="#00CC00" size="2" face="tahoma">email send</font>';
    }
    catch(phpmailerException $e)
    {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**And this is Html code**

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post" style="border:2px solid #03F;width:350px;margin-left:400px;">
<table width="400" >
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">To:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="to" id="to" style="border:2px solid #060"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">Subject:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" style="border:2px solid #060"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">Content</td>
    <td><textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="5" id="content" style="border:2px solid #060"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" value="SEND"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: *Why* should they use phpmailer? *How* does it solve their problem?